# Monotonic decreasing quotient of two $\cosh$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\cosh(ax)}{\cosh(bx)},$ with $0<a<b$ constants. I would like to investigate, if this function is monotonically decreasing for $0<x<\infty$? I plotted the graph and it looks as if it is decreasing. But I have problems in showing this. Do you have a hint for me?

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{a\sinh(ax)\cosh(bx)-b\cosh(ax)\sinh(bx)}{\cosh^2(bx)}.$$
Now $f'(x)<0$ iff $a\sinh(ax)\cosh(bx)<b\cosh(ax)\sinh(bx)$ that is
$a\tanh(ax)<b\tanh(bx)$ which holds because $0<a<b$ and $\tanh(t)$ is positive and increasing for $t>0$.

Comment: +1 I was writing a similar solution and noted your post.

Comment: @Dr. MV Sorry for the overlapping!

Comment: No need for an apology for being faster.